# Latest Silverlight 4 SDK- missing properties?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have what I believe to be the latest SL4 SDK and tools for Visual Studio 2010. However, I seem to be missing certain properties that I would expect to be seeing.

As an example, when editing a XAML textblock control, I am not seeing the TargetNullValue, StringFormat and FallBackValue properties. I have added a reference to the System.Windows.Data but still nothing shows in the XAML editor.

Can anyone confirm whether I should be seeing these properties or is there something else I should be doing to make these properties visible?

Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm: ¿are you using those properties inside a Binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They show up for me.

Make sure you are setting up a proper binding:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="testing" Text="{Binding TargetNullValue=Value}" />
```

Comment: Ah - that was the problem. Thanks to Nestor too